# Typescript make an attribute optionnal in an interface with inneritance

Tags: typescript, types, interface

My objectiv is to clone an interface but changing some parameters.
I got a default generated interface from my database like this one

```
interface Db {
  id: number;
  name: text;
  ...
}
```

The interface is pretty long and that's why I don't want to copy all of that (and also because If the database model change, I don't want to manually change my second interface).

So, my second interface should be exactly the same as the database one BUT with the id in optional

I tried:

```
interface NewInterface extends Db {
  id ?: number;
}
```

But it return me an error: `id is need in ... but optionnal in ...`

I prefere also to avoid using delete operator in my code.
But it doesn't work, does any one have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your NewInterface this way:

```
interface NewInterface extends Omit<Db, 'id'> {
    id?: number; 
}
```